# How to know the current folder depth of a recursive file scanning

Tags: java, recursion

I wrote a function that recursively scans a folder to search for files and process them (`foundFile()`).

the problem is when the function finds an alias folder (for example in a mac, when I am trying to loop in a `/Volumes` folder). the script loops infinitely (I don't know why). is there a possibility to know the current "depth" of the recursion and to stop at (ie) 20?

or even to stop the loop in that particular case (alias folder)

```
private String[] types = { ".wav", ".mp3", ".ogg", ".wave", ".wma"};
public void listFile(String pathname) {
    File f = new File(pathname);
    File[] listfiles = f.listFiles();
    if(listfiles!=null){
        for (int i = 0; i < listfiles.length; i++) {
            if (listfiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                File[] internalFile = listfiles[i].listFiles();
                if(internalFile!=null){
                    for (int j = 0; j < internalFile.length; j++) {
                        for(int h=0;h<types.length;h++){
                            if(internalFile[j].getAbsolutePath().endsWith(types[h])){
                                found.put(types[h], found.get(types[h])+1);
                                foundFile(internalFile[j]);
                            }
                        }
                        if (internalFile[j].isDirectory()) {
                            String name = internalFile[j].getAbsolutePath();
                            listFile(name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                processed+=1;
                for(int j=0;j<types.length;j++){
                    if(f.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(types[j])){
                        this.found.put(types[j], found.get(types[j])+1);
                        foundFile(listfiles[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simply hand through the depth as parameter for you `listFile` method, increment it with each call and stop recursion, when the desired depth is reached.

Comment: You have to pass a level parameter to each recursive call, and increment it when you do the recursion.

Comment: this way you calculate how many folder you have visited. not te depth

Comment: No, if you're using a method parameter, you are effectively calculating the depth.

Comment: ok. now I got it. I was wrong... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, add a level parameter:

```
public void listFile(final String pathname, int level) {
    if (level == 20){
        return;
    }
    final File f = new File(pathname);
    final File[] listfiles = f.listFiles();
    if (listfiles != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listfiles.length; i++) {
            if (listfiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                final File[] internalFile = listfiles[i].listFiles();
                if (internalFile != null) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < internalFile.length; j++) {
                        for (int h = 0; h < types.length; h++) {
                            if (internalFile[j].getAbsolutePath().endsWith(types[h])) {
                                found.put(types[h], found.get(types[h]) + 1);
                                foundFile(internalFile[j]);
                            }
                        }
                        if (internalFile[j].isDirectory()) {
                            final String name = internalFile[j].getAbsolutePath();
                            listFile(name, level + 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                processed += 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
                    if (f.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(types[j])) {
                        this.found.put(types[j], found.get(types[j]) + 1);
                        foundFile(listfiles[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a bug in your recursive call - that should be "level+1", not "level++".

Comment: @Sbodd Ok!, It´s changed